# Glue API createTable not recognising data when specifying partitions with s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am trying to programmatically create a glue tables with the AWS Javascript SDK glue methods from a set of parquet files that are already stored in s3 folders using the normal partition format partition_name=partition.

This is code that creates the table:

```
      let params = {
      DatabaseName: ENV + "_" + orgType,
      TableInput: {
        Name: tableName,
        Description: record.dynamodb.NewImage.name.S.toLowerCase(),
        StorageDescriptor: {
          Columns: [
            {
              Name: "upc",
              Type: "string",
            },
            {
              Name: "store_id",
              Type: "string",
            },
            {
              Name: "date_key",
              Type: "int",
            },
            {
              Name: "items_sold",
              Type: "bigint",
            },
            {
              Name: "total_sales",
              Type: "bigint",
            },
            {
              Name: "average_unit_cost",
              Type: "double",
            },
            {
              Name: "product_name",
              Type: "string",
            },
            {
              Name: "category",
              Type: "string",
            },
            {
              Name: "sub_category",
              Type: "string",
            },
            {
              Name: "year",
              Type: "string",
            },
            {
              Name: "month",
              Type: "string",
            },
            {
              Name: "day",
              Type: "string",
            },
            {
              Name: "id",
              Type: "string",
            },
          ],
          Location:
            "s3://xxxxx-aggregated/by-day/supplier_id=xxxxxxx/",
          InputFormat:
            "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat",
          OutputFormat:
            "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat",
          Compressed: false,
          NumberOfBuckets: -1,
          SerdeInfo: {
            SerializationLibrary:
              "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe",
            Parameters: {
              "serialization.format": "1",
            },
          },
          BucketColumns: [],
          SortColumns: [],
          Parameters: {
            classification: "parquet",
            compressionType: "none",
            typeOfData: "file",
          },
          StoredAsSubDirectories: false,
        },
        PartitionKeys: [
          {
            Name: "retailer_id",
            Type: "string",
          },
        ],
        TableType: "EXTERNAL_TABLE",
        Parameters: {
          classification: "parquet",
          compressionType: "none",
          typeOfData: "file",
        },
      },
    };
    console.log("create table params:", params);
    await glue.createTable(params).promise();
```

There is a path `retailer_id=4291021_96/` below the `s3://xxxxx-aggregated/by-day/supplier_id=xxxxxxx/` path which contains a parquet file. If I crawl the `s3://xxxxx-aggregated/by-day/supplier_id=xxxxxxx/` folder, then it picks up the retailer_id path as a partition and queries work fine. BUT if I create the table using the code above, the table returns zero records when queried with Athena.

If I replace

```
        PartitionKeys: [
          {
            Name: "retailer_id",
            Type: "string",
          },
        ],
```

with:

```
        PartitionKeys: [ ],
```

Then it creates the table and queries work, but there's no 'retailer_id' column or partition.

The AWS documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html is pretty opaque so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Any help getting the create table API to create the table with the partitions intact gratefully received.

Comment: You mentioned that after crawling the path the queries start to work. In the case when the table is created without crawling how are you populating the table's partitions?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response - I got totally waylaid afterward, but your comment is correct: I needed to add the partitions, too. I incorrectly assumed that the partitions would be created when I set the partitionKeys properties!